# Can you have multiple API routes in one file NextJS (Pages directory)

Tags: javascript, next.js

I'm new to NextJS and am trying to learn the API. In the default `hello.js` file inside of the `api` folder there is an `export default function` which returns a JSON response. So now if I want to add another route would I have to create a separate file for that or just add a function below to do so? I would like to just be able to add more functions to create more routes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can have dynamic api routes just like you can have dynamic pages!

From the docs

> For example, the API route pages/api/post/[pid].js has the following code:

```
export default function handler(req, res) {
  const { pid } = req.query
  res.end(`Post: ${pid}`)
}
```

> Now, a request to /api/post/abc will respond with the text: Post: abc.

So you could definitely have different functions based on the api route you are trying to get to. You could use a switch or whatever works for you.

[Docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/routing/api-routes#dynamic-api-routes)

Answer (score 0):

i think you want to have different http method for an api route, right

you can with check method

```
 export default function handler(req, res) {
  if (req.method === 'POST') {
    // Process a POST request
  } else {
    // Handle any other HTTP method
  }
}
```